# Copy e-mail address from contact's properties in Outlook

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, address-book

I'm in an Active Directory environment (Exchange 2003). I'm using Outlook 2007. I want to copy a contact's e-mail address to another application. The display names in our organization are "Lastname, Firstname" so don't contain the actual address. When I double-click on it to open a contact's properties->E-mail Addresses tab then I can see the SMTP address but can't copy any information (tried Ctrl+C and right-clicking).

How to copy the e-mail address? There's got to be a better way than actually rewriting it letter by letter every time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to export all your contacts as a CSV file and then open that file up in Excel, where you can remove any columns you do not need.  The other application will probably also be able to import from the edited CSV file or Excel file.

You did not mention which version of Outlook you are using, as the process of exporting a CSV file has changed a few times.

Comment: I actually did mention it (Outlook 2007). Thanks for the suggestion - I'm familiar with the export process but it seems incredible that there's no other way. It's especially irritating since contacts from outside the organization (with, say, @gmail.com addresses) have a different properties window where the e-mail address is visible and copyable.

Answer (score 1):

you could use the import /export direct to program/or if unable to copy the ms outlook pesonal folders files. Go to outlook in windows explorer - select the file types with .pst/outlook.pst/ and archive.pst[ you may have to unhide files types]-select edit menu -copy the files you want to the program or to a folder you made.Depending on the program you wish to move them to you may have to paste from folder one at a time.

Comment: sorry paradroid, logging at same time, a little diff. but not much

Answer (score 1):

You can also right click the contact and select "Send mail". This brings up a new mail window with the contact's email address in the To field. Not a very elegant method, but in terms of clicks, equivalent to viewing emails of contacts outside the organization mentioned in the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Right click the name in outlook TO: list, choose "Add to outlook contacts". This will open the contact-editing window and you can easily copy the email address from here, before closing the window unsaved